# Custom checklist with radio buttons in Sharepoint possible?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a need to create either a checklist, questionnaire or some sort of custom list in Sharepoint to track Group Ownership in Active Directory.

Currently, this form is a paper form that is printed out, given to the owner of the Group in AD to sign, effectively 'approving' the members of the group and verifying that they are allowed to be in that group.

Basically, we have some Powershell scripts that help make our lives easier. The first one reaches into a text file, grabs the A/D Group Names we have specified, and returns a .CSV of all group members, and some AD meta data such as 'Description' 'Network ID' whether the group member is 'Nested' and the 'Group Owner'. The second one grabs each .CSV file in the directory specified, and imports them into a custom list for processing.

My intentions, are to have a Workflow initiated when the .CSV is added to my Sharepoiint list, however I am not experienced enough with Sharepoint Workflows to determine the best course of action here.

The requirements are simple: I need to pull each .CSV created in a specific directory, into my list (this step is already functional) and then initiate a workflow that lists all group members with check boxes, or a similar way to select them in an email to the 'Group Owner' with an 'Approve' link somewhere....but I am not sure which tools provided by Sharepoint would be best for this particular situation.

Thank you for any and all advise!

Comment: Not sure about this, so I'll add as a comment instead of an answer. It sounds like you might be able to use an InfoPath form. If you already have the group members in a SP list, you can pull those list items into a multi-selection dropdown in the form. The end result will be a list of the users with a checkbox beside each one. You'll have to use some code behind the form to write the selected values into the form's XML when the owner clicks the Approve button, but the saved form would also give you written approval that you keep in a forms library for records purposes.

Comment: Seems doable, I will throw something together tomorrow morning and update accordingly!

Comment: [This](http://amarenderpeddamalku.blogspot.com/2013/07/sharepoint-infopath-2010-cascading_2.html) link is relevant to the process highlighted by @Omegacron I am still working through this now, but wanted to post that for future users who might have similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of juggling with files, maybe you could use SharePoint lists?

How I see it at a high level:

- build a SharePoint list of AD group names
- build a SharePoint list of group members, with a lookup to the above list, a field for approver, and a field (checkbox or drop-down) for approval
- populate the list via PowerShell (no need for csv)
- send each approver a filtered view of the list (approver=Me). Use a datasheet view for easier status editing

Comment: Thanks @Christophe for the suggestions, I'm interested in the third bullet in particular, as well as the last step. Can you articulate that thought a bit more to someone who is still pretty new to the Sharepoint world?

Comment: Touching on my previous comment, I have begun the process of reconstructing my previous process to match the above. I've got Step 3 figured out, but the last step is now where I am stuck. Any insight, would be most appreciated! I will update here if I get it, otherwise assume I am still struggling. Thanks @Christophe

Comment: Are you asking about Approver=Me? This is a simple filter in a view, what you actually need to use is [Me] (assuming the Approver field is of type People).

Comment: Yes I am inquiring about the 'Approver=Me' concept. Any relevant link(s) you can provide in regards to this subject? I am almost done pushing the information from SP_LIST_OF_AD_NAMES -> SP_LIST_GROUP_MEMBERS using Powershell. I'll begin constructing the Workflow shortly :) Thanks! @Christophe

Comment: The only link I found was to...my blog: http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/09/15/today-me-and-sharepoint/ However your case is slightly different. You need to create a list view, go to the filters section, select the Approver column, equal to, and enter [Me] in the text field. Not sure at which step you're stuck.

Comment: also see the first screenshot on this page: http://www.makdeniz.com/how-to-filter-sharepoint-2010-tasks-which-are-assigned-to-you-and-the-group-your-are-member-of/

Comment: Thanks! I finally got my Powershell script working, pushing the information directly up to a list in Sharepoint. Here is the code for that: http://pastebin.com/xRyvXLCB if anyone wanted. I will be constructing the Workflow today! @Christophe

Comment: @Chritophe I am encountering the following issue here, and I am not sure why:

"The "connection type ":send filter values to" is not compatible with any other web parts on this page"

http://i.imgur.com/8DmnAfh.png


I simply have a custom list, and I would like to "authenticate" based off the 'UserName' column in my Sharepoint list, however I get that error and there is not much help on Google when searching that error.

Comment: I am not sure what the issue could be. There are limitations with connections, depending on the Web Parts and the field types.

Comment: Web part is simply a custom list, and field types are all text. I've created a question here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/97884/when-creating-a-current-user-filter-view-the-connection-type-send-filter-va if you happen to think of anything, let me know there! Thanks @Christophe for making me think smarter

Answer (score 0):

We can create a WebPart Page and that webpart can solve this functionality. Using Event receiver you can track the changes in that list item and an email with that Page url could be send to desired user.